# Draw cubic bezier curve with Chart.js 2.4.0

Tags: chart.js, bezier

I use Chart.js and I need to render a [cubic bezier curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Cubic_B.C3.A9zier_curves)  which mathematically consists of four data points. I do know the coordinates of all the four points, but I wonder how I could tell my chart that it should connect P1 and P4 by considering P2 and P3 as "control points" in the context of a bezier curve.

***UPDATE***:

Meanwhile I stumpled upon the property `capBezierPoints` of the line object having that description:

`If true, bezier control points are kept inside the chart. If false, no restriction is enforced.`

Documentation about that property is rare, so I can only assume that if I set it to false, the control points (in my case I have two control points and one start and one end point) are not drawn. However, I have no clue how I can tell Chart.js which of my points are the control points.

Recently I do pass the four points to my dataset as follows:

```
 var data = {
        datasets: [
            {
                label: "start point",
                data: [
                    {
                        x: bezierCurve.getPoint(0).x,
                        y: bezierCurve.getPoint(0).y
                    },
                    {
                        x: bezierCurve.getPoint(1).x,
                        y: bezierCurve.getPoint(1).y
                    },
                    {
                        x: bezierCurve.getPoint(2).x,
                        y: bezierCurve.getPoint(2).y
                    },
                    {
                        x: bezierCurve.getPoint(3).x,
                        y: bezierCurve.getPoint(3).y
                    }
                ],
                fill: false,
                lineTension: 1,
                borderColor: "blue"
            }

        ]
    }

    var options = {
        responsive: true,
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                type: 'linear',
                position: 'bottom',
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    max: Math.round(maxX * 1.1)
                }
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                display: true,
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    max: Math.round(maxY * 2)
                }
            }]
        },
        legend: {
            display: false
        }
    }

    Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.enabled = false;
    Chart.defaults.global.elements.line.capBezierPoints = false;
    Chart.defaults.global.elements.line.tension = 1.0;

    this.displayedBezierCurveChart = new Chart(context, {
        type: 'line',
        data: data,
        options: options
    });
```

Using that implementation, a line is drawn connecting all four points.
What I need instead is a line connecting start point and end point considering the two control points in between.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this not a thing that's explained by the chart.js API documentation? If not, this is *definitely* a thing to report to the Chart.js people so they can add the information to the docs so that not just you, but everyone after you, can easily find that information. That's not going to happen if you only ask here on SO.

Comment: I read through this [documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/) and found a few aspects on bezier curves, however this documentation does not point out how to pass my control points to the chart. So I do not see that my specific question is referred to. Agree that it is worth to report that to the Chart.js people, however they write on their Github page that stackoverflow is the main support channel. So, any idea how to contact them?

Comment: file an issue explaining that there is information that may need to be added to the documentation, and after giving a complete enough description also link to this issue and note that while SO is supposed to be their main channel of support, no one looked at it. Can't say I'm a fan of people claiming SO is their official support channel, because it leads to situations like this.